# Defining hash globally

Tags: perl, hash

I'm writing some code to process a dataset, but there seems to be a problem that I haven't been able to work out after some time looking. I think (and hope!) the solution is fairly simple, and would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %predictions = ('DAMAGING' => 'Disease',
           'TOLERATED' => 'Polymorphism',
           'A' => 'Ala',
           'C' => 'Cys',
           'D' => 'Asp',
           'P' => 'Pro',
           'V' => 'Val',
           'L' => 'Leu',
           'I' => 'Ile',
           'M' => 'Met',
           'F' => 'Phe',
           'Y' => 'Tyr',
           'W' => 'Trp',
           'H' => 'His',
           'K' => 'Lys',
           'R' => 'Arg',
           'Q' => 'Gln',
           'N' => 'Asn',
           'E' => 'Glu',
           'S' => 'Ser',
           'T' => 'Thr',
           'G' => 'Gly');


while(<>) {
  chomp;
  {
    if (length($_)) {
      ProcessData($_);
    }
  }
}

sub ProcessData {
    my ($line) = @_;
    my @fields = split(/\s+/,$line);
    if ($fields[2] =~ /(.)(\d+)(.)/) {
      my $native = $1;
      my $resnum = $2;
      my $mutant = $3;
      print "$fields[1] $predictions{$native} $resnum $pedictions{$mutant} \n"; 
    }  
}
```

The field that I'm trying to change using the hash looks like this:

`A8726P` and the intended output is something like `Ala 8726 Pro`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message I get is:

Global symbol "%pedictions" requires explicit package name at ./processFathmmPreds.pl line 50.

Comment: you have typo, should be `predictions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to see some sample input data, but I think your problem is that you're accessing the hash `%pedictions` instead of `%predictions`. The code you show gives the error

```
Global symbol "%pedictions" requires explicit package
```

which is a dead give-away.

If I create a file containing the single record

```
AA  BB  A8726P DD EE FF
```

then I get the output

```
BB Ala 8726 Pro
```

which seems to be what you expect.

This tidy-up of your program may help as well. Note that `split ' '` (or just `split` if you're spltting `$_`) is better than `split /\s+/` because the latter will return a null first field if there is any leading space in the record.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %predictions = (
  DAMAGING  => 'Disease',
  TOLERATED => 'Polymorphism',
  A         => 'Ala',
  C         => 'Cys',
  D         => 'Asp',
  P         => 'Pro',
  V         => 'Val',
  L         => 'Leu',
  I         => 'Ile',
  M         => 'Met',
  F         => 'Phe',
  Y         => 'Tyr',
  W         => 'Trp',
  H         => 'His',
  K         => 'Lys',
  R         => 'Arg',
  Q         => 'Gln',
  N         => 'Asn',
  E         => 'Glu',
  S         => 'Ser',
  T         => 'Thr',
  G         => 'Gly'
);

my ($filename) = @ARGV;
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};

while (<$fh>) {
  ProcessData($_) if /\S/;
}

sub ProcessData {
  my ($line) = @_;
  my @fields = split ' ', $line;

  if ($fields[2] =~ /\A(.)(\d+)(.)\z/) {
    my $native = $1;
    my $resnum = $2;
    my $mutant = $3;

    print "$fields[1] $predictions{$native} $resnum $predictions{$mutant} \n";

  }
}
```

**output**

```
P45381 Arg 168 Cys 
Q06187 Lys 430 Glu 
P15529 Ser 240 Pro 
P00966 Pro 96 Ser 
P15289 Asp 255 His 
P10275 Gly 820 Ala 
P10275 Asp 864 Gly 
O75828 Val 93 Ile 
P04075 Cys 339 Tyr 
O60885 Ala 371 Gly 
P03950 Lys 84 Glu 
P35670 Val 1146 Met 
P11597 Ala 390 Pro 
Q9UM73 Arg 1275 Leu 
Q99856 Lys 320 Glu 
P12821 Thr 1187 Met 
P10275 Gly 708 Ala 
P15529 Cys 35 Tyr 
P05156 His 183 Arg 
Q06187 Ile 370 Met 
P15056 Glu 586 Lys 
P15289 Pro 231 Thr 
P68133 Gly 270 Cys 
Q9BZ11 Ala 365 Ser 
P15289 Ile 179 Ser 
P35520 Ile 435 Thr 
Q9BWV1 Val 713 Met 
P68133 Pro 334 Ser 
P21549 Gly 190 Arg 
P49748 Gln 159 Arg 
P05067 Ile 716 Val 
P06732 Gly 243 Ala 
P42773 Ala 72 Pro 
P49748 Lys 247 Glu 
O15382 Thr 186 Arg 
P45954 Glu 376 Gly 
Q8WVQ1 Leu 224 Pro 
P02768 Glu 382 Lys 
P06276 Ala 229 Thr 
Q8WXF7 Tyr 196 Cys 
P37023 His 314 Tyr 
Q16790 Gln 326 Arg 
P07451 Val 31 Ile 
P06727 Asn 147 Ser 
P00966 Asp 296 Gly 
P00813 Ala 215 Thr 
P42771 Pro 114 Leu 
P30566 Pro 100 Ala 
P21549 Leu 153 Val 
Q9H8M2 Ala 170 Thr 
O75828 Val 244 Met 
P42771 Gln 50 Arg
```

Comment: so the start of the input file is:

Comment: 1  P45381 R168C DAMAGING

Comment: 2  Q06187 K430E DAMAGING

Comment: Etc for 1000 lines. I tried using the exact code you had written but had some problems - I'm just trying it again now - will let you know how I get on. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I get `P45381 Arg 168 Cys` and `Q06187 Lys 430 Glu` for my code from those two records

Comment: When I try it the script runs without complaint but I don't get any output - any ideas?

Comment: @user3341369: All I can think is that the data is different from what you have shown. I've changed it so that it is self-contained and reads the data from the `DATA` file handle. If that works on your system then you just need to compare your data with what I have in my program

Comment: The real data file is much more messy and I didn't know how to post it without losing its formatting (its the output of a program called fathmm incase you're interested), but even when I make the same data file as you were running on I get no output…!

Comment: You can put it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and link it here. Okay but does the program I've posted run as it stands?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tPruMrL1

Comment: Yes I think so, although I've just been trying and it says no such file of directory when it gets to the while loop, despite the file i specified in the command line and the script being on my desktop. I suspect I may be doing something stupid… I can try and have a friend look at it in person on monday. Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: The program as I have left it doesn't need an input file - it reads from the `DATA` section at the end of the program

Comment: Okay I've run my code against your pastebin and I'm getting `P45381 Arg 168 Cys `, `Q06187 Lys 430 Glu `,  `P15529 Ser 240 Pro `,  `P00966 Pro 96 Ser `,  `P15289 Asp 255 His `,  etc.

Comment: yes it runs fine - thanks! Must be something to do with my input file I assume then...

Comment: Try now please. I've changed it so that it explicitly opens the file and you should get an error message if it can't. If the program's on your desktop then how are you passing the name of the file to open? I've copied your code which expects it as a parameter on the command line, but are you changing your directory to the Desktop before running it from the command line? If you're just double-clicking on the Perl program then you haven't specified an input file at all!

Comment: Fantastic, thank you - it's worked. I realise I hadn't specified .txt in the file name… Thanks again for all your help and time.

Comment: @user3341369: You're welcome. Enjoy your weekend